# How to select specific numbers in a multiplication table (JavaScript)

Tags: javascript

I have an assignment where I have to create a function that returns the sum of all highlighted numbers from this multiplication table:

[image: Numbers]

We have to use a for-loop to solve this assignment, and haven't learned about stuff like arrays, matrixes, and other more advanced concepts that would make this easier.

Here's what I came up with:

```
function pitagorica2(){
  var x = 0, y = 0;
  for (var i = 1; i <=10; i++) {
    x += i*5;
    y += i*6;
  }
  x = x*2 - 25 - 30;
  y = y*2 - 30 - 36;
  return x + y;
}
```

Is there any better way to get to the same result without using more advanced things?

Comment: We're at an extreme beginner level: we have only done variables, constants, functions and for-loops. So yeah... I don't think we can use arrays or algorithms.
It is a nice idea though! @Skin

Comment: For that kind of beginner level the logic in your function seems just fine. You've solved the problem. Only thing I could suggest is naming your variables in a way that they are more explanatory, for example instead of `x` call it `tableFive`. Instead of `x = x*2...` create a new variable `var doubleFive = tableFive*2...`. You could propably use even better names, but hope you understand my meaning. Don't be afraid to use long variable names, as long as they explain what they do. Code readability is a very important (and hard to master) concept, so better start early on this.

Comment: @Bqardi Thanks for the reply! I do understand your point about the variable names, but this was the 14th function exercise I had to do today and kinda got tired of thinking about variable names xD

Comment: Lol, I get it. But practice makes perfect, right. As long as you understand the importance, though.

Comment: What about making it more flexible, maybe? Using parameters to enter any two values (between 1 - 10) as arguments to the function and calculate the correct output? Is that too advanced for the assignment?

Comment: @Bqardi, sorry for the late reply.
Yes I did consider that possibility, and had already made it but didn't think it would be worth posting in the question. 
Here's how I did it:
```
function pitagorica3(column, row){
  var columnSum = 0, rowSum = 0;
  for (var i = 1; i <=10; i++) {
    columnSum += i*column;
    rowSum += i*row;
  }
  columnSum = columnSum*2 - column*column - column*row;
  rowSum = rowSum*2 - row*row - column*row;
  return columnSum + rowSum;
}
```